# Is determinant of general linear matrices unqiue?

Tags: matrices

I read that the general linear group $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ is defined by
$$GL(n, \mathbb R) :=\{A \in\mathbb R^{n\times n} | \det A \neq 0  \}={\det}^{-1}(\mathbb R- {0}).$$

Does the existence of the inverse determinant function $\det^{-1}$ implies that every general linear matrix $A$ has a unique determinant $\det A$? If yes how do we know that it is true?

Comment: Two matrices that differ by a row replacement operation have the same determinant, so the "inverse determinant" function isn't a function. Unless I have misinterpreted the question...

Comment: @SeanRoberson Does that mean the inverse function don't exist? Why then do we define $GL(n, \mathbb R)$ as $\det^{-1}$ if $\det^{-1}$ doesn't exist?

Comment: Now I see. The inverse function doesn't exist, rather the notation $\det ^{-1}$ means the inverse image, or the pullback, of a set.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks. That cleared my confusion.

Comment: Agreed with Roberson. Note that $f:X\to Y$ is any map then $f^{-1}(a)=\{x\in X:f(x)=a\}\subset X$ is the pull back map.